# Can't connect to internet during Ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ethernet

I am fairly useless when it comes to hardware issues, so I appologize if this is a very simple question. I am trying to install Ubuntu on a computer that I purchased from a friend. When I get to the install screen, it says that it doesn't have an internet connection despite being plugged directly into the router (the little connection icon keeps cycling so it seems to be doing something anyway). When I boot to Ubuntu from the USB drive it does the same thing; continuously try to connect to the wired connection but not making any progress.

Running lspci -nnk gives me that my Ethernet controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabyte Ethernet Controller using the r8169 Kernal driver. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit:

tried installing the r8168 driver as suggested here is the trace:

...
Building initial module for 4.2.0-35-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/make.log for more information.

looking in the log we have:

DKMS make.log for r8168-8.037.00 for kernel 4.2.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Tue Apr  5 19:28:43 PDT 2016
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.o
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_tx_vlan_tag’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c:2705:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vlan_tx_tag_present’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     tag = (vlan_tx_tag_present(skb)) ?
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c:2706:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vlan_tx_tag_get’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
           TxVlanTag | swab16(vlan_tx_tag_get(skb)) : 0x00;
           ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_init_one’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c:17103:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SET_ETHTOOL_OPS’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     SET_ETHTOOL_OPS(dev, &rtl8168_ethtool_ops);
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_schedule_work’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.c:18674:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘PREPARE_DELAYED_WORK’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     PREPARE_DELAYED_WORK(&tp->task, task);
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.037.00/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic'

Comment: This problem seems similar to the one solved in http://askubuntu.com/questions/654496/wired-network-connection-in-xubuntu-not-working-with-r8169

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Given that I can't connect to the Internet at all with it, I suppose that I will have to manually install the drivers?

Comment: I tried to install it but the build failed at Building initial model for 4.2.0-35-generic

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first I tried the linked answer, but that didn't build successfully. I then went to the Realtek website and downloaded their 3.x linux driver:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

Extracted it and built it and everything works great :)

Comment: Yep, the manufacturer is always one of the first places we would look for this. They usually have good makefiles, scripts, and readme type files. This issue applies to a lot of HP desktops lately and even their doco is excellent.